# websocket protocol not supported trough Apache2 reverse proxy

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, docker, proxy

We've set up a reverse proxy with Apache2, to hide the port in the URL and in later stages secure our connection with SSL.

We're running a Hawkbit Java container on AWS ECR. We normally go to the service's webpage by entering

```
ip:port/UI
```

Our internship mentor wants to enter **ip/UI** to go to the webpage. We've set up a Apache2 reverse proxy and **are able** to go to the webpage with ip/UI.

However, when we log in as admin, we're not permitted to do anything. We've checked the traffic by using F12 on Firefox and we get a 501 error when trying to establish a websocket.

We're also using an application ELB on AWS. 
We've tried to add the following to our conf file:

```
ProxyPass         /UI  ws://ip:port/UI
ProxyPassReverse  /UI  ws://ip:port/UI
```

but with no effect.

Comment: can't edit yet, but you should put both ProxyPass-lines in 'code'-Syntax (just put 4 blanks in front and an empty above it)

Comment: Did my answer work for you? Would a appreciate a short feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [THIS](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html) --> **mod_proxy_wstunnel**

[...]
This module requires the service of **mod_proxy. It provides support for the tunnelling of web socket connections to a backend websockets server**. The connection is automatically upgraded to a websocket connection:
HTTP Response

```
Upgrade: WebSocket
Connection: Upgrade
```

Proxying requests to a websockets server like echo.websocket.org can be done using the ProxyPass directive:

```
ProxyPass "/ws2/"  "ws://echo.websocket.org/"
ProxyPass "/wss2/" "wss://echo.websocket.org/"
```

Comment: i've tried this, but when I check the connection, the websocket header gets a 501 response, and does not get upgraded